# Cannot find `IBus Preferences` launcher in Unity Dash on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, ibus

I want to setup quick input method but I cannot find `IBus Preferences` launcher in Unity Dash on Ubuntu 16.04.
[image]

I can see the <kbd>iBus</kbd> option selected in the `Language Support`.
[image]

How can I launch the `iBus Preference` window like [this video](https://youtu.be/rvIobt5JpXI?t=50s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the answer.

1. Search and launch the Ubuntu Software.

   [image]
2. Search `ibus` in the search bar and enter the `IBus Preferences`.

   [image]
3. Click <kbd>Launch</kbd> button to launch the `IBus Preferences` dialog.

   [image]

Comment: Shows up as installed, but doesn't show up when searched or in preferences.

Comment: No application found in my case

Answer (score 1):

From terminal, type `ibus-setup`. Tested on ubuntu 22.04.